# Does a Human Rights site exist on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Has a site for human rights related topics already been proposed (women rights, rights of the child, humanitarian law, terrorism law, etc.)? If so, where may we find all these topics as law doesn't have tags for them?

Answer (score 9):

There's [politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags) which is in beta and has tags on [human-rights](/questions/tagged/human-rights) and [civil-rights](/questions/tagged/civil-rights)

There's [law](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) which might cover humanitarian law.

There was an [equality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87275/equality) proposal that would have likely covered women's rights and  rights of the child, but it failed to get the necessary traction.

Your question could be on topic on one of the above depending on what it is. Try the help centre's law and politics first to see whether your question would be on-topic on either of them.

As always, your final recourse if you have a question that's not on-topic anywhere is to propose your own site on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I actually signed on to Stack Exchange to read more on all Human Rights topics. I am not into politics, though I see the reason it's moved inside that forum, as a former human rights law student find equality just as important as ending child marriages,etc. Thanks, Robert! I'd up vote you but there is a Skeptic forum mob on here downvoting all my posts.